# Plot from following inputs

Tags: plotting

I want to  make a graph, where X-axis goes from 0.00-3.00 and the Y-axis goes from 75-100. Then i have theses inputs on a .txt file which i want to plot in this setting. How would i do that?

Link to my text file: [enter link description here](http://textuploader.com/d9brp)

Comment: Look up `Import[]` and `ListPlot[]`.

Comment: how do I refere to the spec. text file in the [] bracket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Part 1

In order to make the X-axis go from 0.00-3.00 and the Y-axis from 75-100 use `PlotRange`.

I extracted `data` from your link.

```
ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {75, 100}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Part 2

If I wanted the 0.0 on the x axis to get ***indented slightly***?

One has complete control over the `Ticks`. One of the forms that can be used is:

```
Ticks -> {{x1, label1, {plen1, mlen1}}, ...}
```

where `x1` is the position, `label1` is the label and `{plen1, mlen1}` represents the lengths above/below the axis.

What is done is to create a list to be used for the ticks. The idea is to set the label for zero to a string padded with some spaces so it will be indented. The number of spaces will control the indentation.

The ticks will be labeled and long for {0, 0.5, 1, ... 3} and short with no label for the other ticks.

First a function is created to do that work for us:

```
specialTick[tick_] := Module[
  {
   label,
   len
   },
  {label, len} = If[
    tick == 0, {"    0.0", {0.02, 0}},
    If[Mod[10*tick, 5] == 
      0, {ToString[NumberForm[tick, {1, 1}]], {0.02, 0}},
     {"", {0.01, 0}}
     ]
    ];
  {tick, label, len}
  ]
```

The function is given the `Listable` attribute.

```
SetAttributes[specialTick, Listable]
```

Next the ticks are created by applying the function to the X-axis range:

```
ticks = specialTick[Range[0, 3, 0.1]]

(* {{0., "    0.0", {0.02, 0}}, {0.1, "", {0.01, 0}}, {0.2, 
  "", {0.01, 0}}, {0.3, "", {0.01, 0}}, {0.4, "", {0.01, 0}}, {0.5, 
  "0.5", {0.02, 0}}, {0.6, "", {0.01, 0}}, {0.7, "", {0.01, 0}}, {0.8,
   "", {0.01, 0}}, {0.9, "", {0.01, 0}}, {1., "1.0", {0.02, 0}}, {1.1,
   "", {0.01, 0}}, {1.2, "", {0.01, 0}}, {1.3, "", {0.01, 0}}, {1.4, 
  "", {0.01, 0}}, {1.5, "2.0", {0.02, 0}}, {1.6, "", {0.01, 0}}, {1.7,
   "", {0.01, 0}}, {1.8, "", {0.01, 0}}, {1.9, "", {0.01, 0}}, {2., 
  "2.0", {0.02, 0}}, {2.1, "", {0.01, 0}}, {2.2, "", {0.01, 0}}, {2.3,
   "", {0.01, 0}}, {2.4, "", {0.01, 0}}, {2.5, 
  "3.0", {0.02, 0}}, {2.6, "", {0.01, 0}}, {2.7, "", {0.01, 0}}, {2.8,
   "", {0.01, 0}}, {2.9, "", {0.01, 0}}, {3., "3.0", {0.02, 0}}} *)
```

Finally, the `ticks` are used in the plot. Note that the zero label has been indented slightly.

```
ListPlot[
 data,
 PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {75, 100}},
 Ticks -> {ticks, Automatic}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Here's one possible way of doing it.

```
data = Import["AbsolutePathToFolder\\points.txt", "Table"]

ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{0.0, 3.0}, {75.0, 100.0}}]
```

Of course, you might want to use relative path or a different kind of plot, depending on your needs.

Comment: if  I wanted the 0.0 on the x axis to get "indented slightly" so to speak how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
Clear[makePlot, extractDataString]
url = "http://textuploader.com/d9brp"
xmlObjects[url_] := Import[url, "XMLObject"]
extractDataString[
  es_] := ( 
    Cases[es, 
      XMLElement["code", {"class" -> "no-highlight"}, xs__] -> xs, 
      Infinity] // Catenate) // StringReplace[#, "{" | "|" -> ""] & //
   First
makePlot[uri_] := 
 Composition[ListPlot , ImportString[#, "Table"] & , 
   extractDataString, xmlObjects][uri]
makePlot[url]
```

Out:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you!
if I wanted the 0.0 on the x axis to get "indented slightly" so to speak how would I do that?

Comment: You are welcome! Jack LaVigne has answered it.