# Inserting additional values into a plot after it has been rendered

Tags: plotting

I have made this nice figure in Mathematica:

[image]

Now I want to add the values from my text file [mytextfile](http://textuploader.com/d93hh) to a plot which I already rendered.

Is there any function I can use to add the a list of values to my already created plot?

Comment: Look up `Import[]`, `ListPlot[]`, and `Show[]`.

Comment: Question has some similarity to [149131](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/149131).

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you have your plot made.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Click in the plot and copy it (**ctrl-C**).

Start a new cell in your notebook and type:

```
plot =
```

and then paste (**ctrl-V**) the plot to the right of the equal sign

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now the symbol `plot` will represent the image.

To plot them together with your `data` use `Show`.

```
Show[
 ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Black],
 plot
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Side note: If you are creating the plot make the assignment to `plot` when you create it. For example:

```
plot = Plot[fun[x], {x, 0, 3}, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

Answer (score 0):

In[1]:

```
SeedRandom[1]
points = RandomInteger[100, {100, 2}];
Dynamic@ListPlot[points]
```

Out[1]:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In[2]:

```
newPoints = RandomInteger[100, {50, 2}];
points = Join[points, newPoints];
```

Out[1]:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: "[...]  to my already created graph"

Comment: I am not sure if they are  the same person or in a same team. At least I have answered it once. The new question is how to update the plot but not how to  import data from a text file. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/147082/plot-from-following-inputs/147084#147084

Answer (score 0):

If, instead, adding points to an existing curve is desired (which is how I originally interpreted the question), do the following.  For instance, with the plot

```
plt = Plot[85 + 1/x, {x, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> {84, 100}]
```

[image]

add points (chosen somewhat randomly, so that they stand out)

```
newpts = {{.5, 85}, {2., 90.}};
plt /. Line[z_] -> Line[Sort[Join[pts, newpts]]]
```

[image]