# How to set the properties of a plot that's already been plotted?

Tags: plotting, graphics

Let's say I have a function that I've plotted, like so:

```
a = Plot[f, {x, 0, 5}, Background -> Blue]
```

[image]

So I don't really have access to the function anymore, but I want to replot it with a changed property of the graph, for example, I want to make the color of the line `Black`, or the background `Red`.

How can I do that without replotting it, or not having access to the function again?

I know I can access the original color using `Option[]`, like:

```
Last@Last@Options[a, Background]
```

But `SetOptions` and `SetProperty` don't really work. It seems like `SetOptions` sets the general property for plots in general, and `SetProperty` isn't for this. (`SetProperty[a, Background -> Red]` gives the error that my plot isn't an object with properties. `SetOptions[a, Background -> Red]` says that my argument plot isn't a symbol or stream.)

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `Show[a, Background -> Yellow]`?

Comment: @kglr thank you, but that won't really work for my application... let me update my question to be more specific. Also, would that work for PlotStyle anyway?

Comment: related/possible duplicate Q/A: [Is it possible to change the color of plot in Show?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17250/125). See, especially, [Mr.Wizard's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17270/125)

Comment: Related: "[Where can I get detailed information on how the Plot command works?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55535/280)"

Answer (score 6):

If you have the plot in Mathematica format (for instance saved in an unexecuted Mathematica notebook) but not the code that created it, then copy it into a new line of code, like

[image]

to obtain the same plot with a blue background.  The point is, without the code to generate the plot, execute the instructions directly on the plot itself.

[image]

**Addendum**

It is natural to ask whether the approach give by kgir would work with the more complicate plot used in this answer.

[image]

[image]

The line styles are changed, but the background is not.  The reason can be seen from

[image]

```
(* {} *)
```

`Background` does not appear in the internal code for the plot, so it cannot be changed in this way.  Instead, `Append` the command to the plot.  (Using `Show`, as above, also would work in this case.)

[image]

[image]

More generally, for complicated plots it is necessary to peer inside the plot by

[image]

and tailor the needed commands to change or add to the internal instructions of the plot.  For instance, one might then use

[image]

which both removes the old line styling commands and adds the new ones, to obtain the plot just above.

**Second Addendum**

As requested in a comment below, the code used to create the original plot is

```
Plot[Flatten@Table[{MathieuCharacteristicA[r, q], 
    MathieuCharacteristicB[r + 1, q], -MathieuCharacteristicA[r, q], 
   -MathieuCharacteristicB[r + 1, q],}, {r, 0, 1}], {q, 0, 8}, 
   Evaluated -> True, PlotRange -> {All, {0, 4}}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Blue], Directive[Thick, Red], 
       Directive[Thick, Dashed, Blue], Directive[Thick, Dashed, Red]}, 
   Filling -> Table[{2 n + 1 -> {{2 n + 2}, Directive[Opacity[1/2], Purple]}}, {n, 0, 3}]]
```

which is based on a [recent question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/149105/1063).

Comment: (1) could you please post the code that generate the plot in your answer; (2) your remark ( _Background does not appear in the internal code for the plot_ ) is incorrect, you should have used `Cases[graphicsobject, HoldPattern[Background -> _],  Infinity]`. `Background` is not a function so, unsurprisingly,  the pattern `_Background` does not match anything

Comment: ... forgot to add: if the input graphics object didn't have an explicit `Background` option, the replacement rule `/. {HoldPattern[Background -> _] :> Rule[Background, Red],  ll_Line :> {Thick, Dashed, ll}` wouldn't work. But, the OP's input plot already has `Background`,

Comment: @kglr  Thanks for pointing out that my original search for `Background` was incorrect.  I have replaced it, but with the same result.  I also searched the code by eye and could not find it.  I agree that lack of this option is surprising.  As requested, I also posted the code I used (in a separate notebook) to generate the original plot.  Please be assured that my answer was not meant to criticize yours in any way but only to point out that for complicated plots it may be necessary to tailor the commands the change the plot to the details of the plot's internal code.

Comment: Actually `Show` is the idiomatic and recommended way to add/replace option(s) in a `Graphics` object which will work regardless of whether the latter contains the option(s) or not. `Append` will not work if the `Graphics` object already contains the option(s).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov  I agree that `Show` is the better way for changes that can be accomplished by specifying options.  I used `Append` simply to show that alternatives exist in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

```
a = Plot[{x Sin[1/x], x Cos[1/x]}, {x, -1/2, 1/2}, Background -> Blue]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
a /. {HoldPattern[Background->_] :> Rule[Background, Red], 
    ll_Line :> {Thick, Dashed, ll}}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note: `a /. {Rule[Background, _] :> Rule[Background, Red], ll_Line :> {Thick, Dashed, ll}}` also works.

Update: If the input plot does not have an explicit `Background` option, as in

```
b = Plot[{x Sin[1/x], x Cos[1/x]}, {x, -1/2, 1/2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

then the replacement rule above would not work. You could use

```
Show[b, Background->Red]/. { ll_Line :> {Thick, Dashed, ll}}
```

to get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

See [this answer by Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17270/125) for methods to modify plot styles in more general ways.